# AWS CDK - How to deploy EC2 instances to multiple regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using the following resource to create my instances in AWS.

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cdk-ec2-userdata-example

What I really want to implement is just creating multiple (specified) instances on AWS with CDK.

Example:

```
us-east-1 => Number of EC2 instances: 2
eu-west-1 => Number of EC2 instances: 1
```

And what about VPC? Can I share the created VPC or do I need to use the default VPC?

Instances will operate independently.

Comment: This [page](https://gizmo.codes/building-a-muti-region-app-with-aws-cdk-part-1/) shows an example of how to create an AppStack per region from a single CDK app. Generally, I would advise against using the default VPC. Individual apps should have their own, dedicated VPC imo.

Comment: Would that work globally? In the example, all the regions are based on the US. Some other resources says that is not possible without using CodeBuild Pipeline. (ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v74PvMEhMhQ&ab_channel=CDKDay)

Comment: That's making use of CDK Pipelines specifically, which you'd use for CI/CD (if that's your goal). But you can write a simple CDK app that targets [multiple stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/stack_how_to_create_multiple_stacks.html) and each of those stacks can, afaik, be deployed into a different regions. There's really no difference between US vs. non-US regions here (AWS service feature parity notwithstanding). I would expect it to be quick to test a VPC with one EC2 instance in multiple regions, US and non-US.